# Perl script to print out cars model and car color

Tags: perl

I am tying to create a perl script to printout car models and colors, and the data is below.  I want to know if there is anyway to make the car model heading a field so that I can print it any time I want to?  the data below is a csv file.  the way I want the data to look on a report is below as well

********This is how the data looks********

```
Chevy
blue,1978,Washington 
brown,1989,Dallas
black,2001,Queens
white,2003,Manhattan

Toyota
red,2003,Bronx
green,2004,Queens
brown,2002,Brooklyn
black,1999,Harlem
```

***********This is how I am trying to get the data to look in a report***********

Car Model:Toyota

Color:Red Year:2002 City: Queens

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Names like "Toyota" and "Chevy" are car *makes*, not models. Models are things like "Camry" or "Tahoe."

Comment: So do you want the make line repeated for each data line or do you want the make line once for each set of data lines?  The first option appears to be what you get from the current crop of responses but I suspect what you really want is the second option.  Unfortunately, your output example shows only one line of data so it's hard to tell what is intended.

Answer (score 4):

```
open my $fh, '<', 'filename' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;
    my @fields = split /,/, $_;
    print("Car Model: $fields[0]\n"), next if @fields == 1;

    my %data;
    @data{qw( color year city )} = @fields;
    print "Color:$data{color} Year:$data{year} City:$data{city}\n";
}
```

Comment: Woah, using an array as the key to a hash...?

Comment: I would like to print on make (sorry you are right) and then list all of the cars under that one make and not have it repeat for each car.
example

chevy
car info info
car info info
car info info
car info info

Ford
car info info
car info info
car info info
car info info

Toyota
car info info
car info info
car info info
car info info

Thanks for your help

Comment: open my $fh, '<', 'filename' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;
    my @fields = split /,/, $_;
    print("Car Model: $fields[0]\n"), next if @fields == 1;

    my %data;
    @data{qw( color year city )} = @fields;
    print "Color:$data{color} Year:$data{year} City:$data{city}\n";
}

this worked!  thanks!  how can I get the output so show up the same way if I wanted to make it a .html file?

Answer (score 1):

```
open IN, "< somefile";
while (<IN>) {
  chomp;
  if (m/,/) {
    @temp = split /,/, $_;
    printf "Car model: %s\nColor: %s\nYear: %s\nCity: %s\n\n", $make, @temp;
  } else {
    $make = $_;
  }  
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't run under use strict, which all code should be using.   Also, 3-arg open is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in CSV files with [Text::CSV](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldoc?Text::CSV). That module will catch all the edge cases that you are likely to miss in your own implementation.

Check out [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) and [perldoc perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for help on perl data structures.

Answer (score 0):

I would go through the file line by line and for each line (pseudo-code, not tested) :

```
if ($line ~= /\w+,\d+,\w+/) { # matches the lines with the information
    my $array = split $line at , 
    print to file array[0] + "," + array[1] + "," + array[2] + "\n"
} elsif ($line ~= /\w+/) { # matches the car model since the information was already matched
    print "Car Model:" + $line + "\n"
} else {   # must be the whitespace so you know the information about the car is done
    print "\n" # to separate the car information
}
```

If you don't have the blank line in your csv file then do the newline to separate the car models elsewhere